# iOS badge not incrementing when sending a push

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, badge

Starting last Thursday (03/03/2016), the iOS badge is not updating when sending a push using Parse. The badge stays at "1" no matter how many pushes are sent. Once the app is opened, the badge is reset. When the next push arrives the count is "1" again and it stays there for all future pushes till the app is opened.

We are using the correct format of badge: "Increment" in the data for the Push notification. The behavior is the same even if we are sending a "campaign" push from the Parse dashboard. What is strange is that badge count was incrementing correctly till Wednesday last week (03/02/2016). We did not make any changes to the code whatsoever.

Comment: Maybe it's a day behind... leap year might have something to do with it?

Comment: Your apns payload may be having the badge count 1 always, the payload should have bigger count.. And it will never reset until you do it, you must be resetting it.

Comment: Are you using the hosted version? or your own server? Did you maybe do a pull from the git repo that could have broken something?

Comment: I am using the hosted version still. We haven't migrated to our server.

Comment: @iphonic : We are resetting the badge count whenever the app is opened. How do I reset the apns payload ?

Comment: I'm noticing this as well on Parse.com

Comment: Looks like a bug on Parse. I found a bug report on this as well: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/469147319941911/

Comment: This seems to be fixed today. We are no longer seeing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

it can't complete the increment all by the client self when it did'nt stay active. you need the server to change the badge value.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.